# Undefined identifier trying to write a function

Tags: c++, boolean

I am a student and am tasked with creating a program that will determine if a person is rich or not.  My code is below and I keep getting an error that `identifier "isRich" is undefined`.  Can someone help me figure out where I went wrong?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream> //for input and output
#include "Cusick Project 5.h"
using namespace std;


void calcWealth(int age, long cash, int dependants, long debt)
{

cout << "Please enter your age: ";
cin >> age;
cout << "Please enter the amount of cash on hand: ";
cin >> cash;
cout << "Please enter the amount of dependents you have: ";
cin >> dependants;
cout << "Please enter the amount of money you owe";
cin >> debt;

bool isRich(int *age, long *cash, int *dependants, long *debt);
{
    long trueCash;
    bool status = false;

    trueCash = cash - debt;

    if (dependants == 0)
    {
        if (trueCash >= 1000000)
        {
            status = true;
        }
        else
            status = false;
    }

    else if (age < 40)
    {
        trueCash = trueCash - (dependants * 150000);
        if (trueCash >= 1000000)
        {
            status = true;
        }
        else
            status = false;
    }

    else if (age > 39 && age < 51)
    {
        trueCash = trueCash - (dependants * 75000);

        if (trueCash >= 1000000)
        {
            status = true;
        }
        else
            status = false;
    }

    else
    {
        trueCash = trueCash - (dependants * 25000);

        if (trueCash >= 1000000)
        {
            status = true;
        }
        else
            status = false;
    }
  }
}

int main()
{
    int age;
    long cash;
    int dependants;
    long debt;
    bool status; 

    cout << "Welcome to the wealth indicator..." << endl;

    calcWealth(age, cash, dependants, debt);

    if (isRich(status) = true)
    {
        cout << "Congratulations!  We consider you as being \"rich.\"" <<     endl;
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "I am sorry!  You are not yet \"rich.\"" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, you should not pollute a question with needless instructions of your assignment.

Comment: After you fix the missing `}` braces and the indirections in `isRich`, note that you define `isRich` as taking 4 arguments, but call it with only 1. Also that none of the local variables in `main` is initialized since `status` is never set, and the others are passed by value to `calcWealth`.

Comment: I will give you free advise rewrite your code again. When you do that after each written line write `cout << "\nSOMETHING\n";` compile and see what happened and if it compile correctly. That how you can actually learn how to make working code.

Comment: Thanks @Logman...I will start over.

Comment: In `if (isRich(status) = true)`, change `=` to `==`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra semicolon after the declaration of `isRich()`.

Your code should instead look like:

```
...    
bool isRich(int *age, long *cash, int *dependants, long *debt)
{
...
```

Also, you are missing a closing `}` at the end of the function `calcWealth()`, right before the declaration of `isRich()`.

Comment: @Jaime, if this answers your question, could you please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the question?

Comment: Did you try to compile his code? It's to much mess to just repair semicolon problem. For ex. he pass age as pointer and use it like value.

Comment: @Logman It is, indeed, a mess, but the semicolon and closing brace fix _the immediate problem_ about which he was asking.

Comment: @Alex thanks for the help - this did help my initial problem, but obviously I had other issues.  I'm starting over.

Answer (score 0):

Minus the `cin` statements, your first few lines look like

```
void calcWealth(int age, long cash, int dependants, long debt)
{

// ...

bool isRich(int *age, long *cash, int *dependants, long *debt);
{
```

but you can't start declaring `isRich` *inside* `calcWealth`. You need to tell the compiler the first function is finished, with a `}`.

BTW that function won't do what you want anyway - the values it reads in are lost - but that's another question.

For reference, if you have a compile error, it comes with a line number. By not showing which line it fails on, you're asking everyone to *guess* something the compiler already told you.

Comment: Thank you for the information - I will be sure to include it next time.